# "The {0} field is required" message localisation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 I'm using custom `IStringLocalizer` service and after configuration most of my web site is translated except the default required field message even after I set `ModelBindingMessageProvider` and `DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider`

**Model**

```
public class EmailModel
{

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress()]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Phone]
    [Display(Name = "Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Message")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup.css  (ConfigureServices method)**

```
  services
            .AddMvc(options =>
                {
                    var L = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IStringLocalizer>();
                    options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueIsInvalidAccessor(
                        (x) => L["The value '{0}' is invalid."]);
                    options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustBeANumberAccessor(
                        (x) => L["The field {0} must be a number."]);
                    options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetMissingBindRequiredValueAccessor(
                        (x) => L["A value for the '{0}' property was not provided.", x]);
                    options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetAttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor(
                        (x, y) => L["The value '{0}' is not valid for {1}.", x, y]);
                    options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetMissingKeyOrValueAccessor(
                        () => L["A value is required."]);
                    options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetUnknownValueIsInvalidAccessor(
                        (x) => L["The supplied value is invalid for {0}.", x]);
                    options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustNotBeNullAccessor(
                        (x) => L["Null value is invalid.", x]);
                })
            .AddViewLocalization()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver())
              .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => {
                  options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                  {
                      return  services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IStringLocalizer>();
                  };
              })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
services.AddTransient<IStringLocalizer, Services.XMLStringLocalizerService>();
```

**In my xml localization file  (my service don't using resource files) I have this strings:**

"The {0} field is not a valid phone number."  - works fine

"The {0} field is required" - not working because service don't ever receive any required message that looks like this.

**So any idea what I'm missing ?**

I knew that there few soultions such as
1) Set ErrorMessage
2)Creating new class that Inherited  RequiredArtibbute class and set default message in class constructor

**But my goal is to change DEFAULT message of RequierdAtrribute**

Comment: I put your code in a new project and it works for me. it shows the message `"The {0} field is required"` every time i don't provide value for a field.

Comment: And you are sure that when you are changing language this string is also changing?

Comment: no it does not change, i was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

For localization/customization of DataAnnotation error messages, it must be provided in the property attributes, otherwise the default message will be triggered.

if you have done `.AddDataAnnotationLocalization(...)` in the stratup use it like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage ="The field '{0}' is required")]
[Display(Name = "Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

or, if you don't want to use startup settings and specify an error message from a specific shared resource (assuming that you have resource file named "MyResources") :

```
[Required(
    ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(MyResources.Required),
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyResources))]
[Display(
    Name = nameof(MyResources.Name),
    ResourceType = typeof(MyResources))]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: I knew about ErrorMessage     but I want to change DEFAULT message

Comment: it is already in the answer, you can specify whatever message you want there.

Comment: btw, what do you exactly mean by “change DEFAULT message”? is it the messages that are displayed when you use the Required attribute without providing any custom message?

Comment: Yes exactly what I mean

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no simple solution, it is still an open issue here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6696

Comment: Thx, for link. It's seems that I'm not only one with this problem